# Creating text box with magnifier to search and select account from org

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller, inputfield

I am trying to develop a Visualforce page to search account and select from the org. Like we select an account on the contact.

Need something like this on the page:

[image]

Controller:

```
public with sharing class TestControllerForIssue{

  private final Account acct;

    public TestControllerForIssue(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    }

}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="TestControllerForIssue">
    <apex:form >
            <apex:inputField id="accountNameForTheProduct" value="{!account.Name}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am only seeing a text box on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookup icon will be visible when you bind the `inputField` with lookup/master detail field or you will have to create it custom.

If you don't want to create a custom lookup, and if you want to display the lookup of `Account` on any other object's page, then that object should have the lookup/master detail field looking up to `Account` object. Then, you would be able to bind that field to your visualforce page. Assuming, you are creating visualforce page with standard controller as `Contact`

In that case, your controller would be

```
public with sharing class TestControllerForIssue{
    public  Contact con {get;set;}
    public TestControllerForIssue(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.con = (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
    }
}
```

And visualforce page would be

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TestControllerForIssue">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocksection >
                <apex:inputField id="accountNameForTheProduct" value="{!con.AccountId}"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If you want to display the `Account's` lookup while using the standard controller of `Account`, then you will have to use another `object's` instance which has relation with `Account` or you can create self lookup to `Account` and you can use that field for binding.

Controller using `Account` as standard controller and using `Contact's` field

```
public with sharing class TestControllerForIssue{
  public Contact con {get;set;}
  public Account acct {get;set;}
    public TestControllerForIssue(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    }
}
```

And visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="TestControllerForIssue">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocksection >
                <apex:inputField id="accountNameForTheProduct" value="{!con.AccountId}"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```